# Bash command to split one line of text into 2 lines

Tags: shell-script

I want this line of a text file

```
This is to become line 1 and that is line 2
```

To be split into 2 lines, like this:

```
This is to become line 1
and that is line 2
```

Note that I don't want to edit/cut/remove anything, not a single character, I just want to end up with 2 lines of text instead of one, and to be able to decide where the split should take place.
How can I use `sed` or `awk` or `split` to do this?
Don't really care which one I use, but I would prefer `sed`, if possible...

Comment: What you have done so far ?

Comment: What is the criterion for choosing the split point?

Comment: Are you just talking about displaying the file in the terminal? You can't turn one line into two lines without inserting a newline char, or converting an existing char to a newline.

Comment: Criteria choosing the split point is random, depending on raw file fetched from a website with wget.

Comment: NO, I'm trying to build a script to fetch, edit and post weather data from a weather website in a conky

Comment: Your split criterion is a bit too vague. Maybe `fold` is of interest to you - you can e.g. choose a number of characters after which a newline will be inserted - will split in the middle of words, though. I think you'll have to be more specific about your needs...

Answer (score 1):

Well this will work if you are trying to split the line at the word "and."

```
echo "This is to become line 1 and that is line 2" | sed 's/and/\nand/g' 
This is to become line 1 
and that is line 2
```

Please note that your mileage may vary depending on which sed version you are using.

UPDATE:

In order to get the  split you simply add the "\n" in front of the term/element you wish to use as the start of the second line.

```
echo "Sun rise: <...strong...>07:24 am<../..strong..><..br ../..> Sun set: <..strong..>07:31 pm<../..strong..><..br.. /..> " | sed 's/Sun set/\nSun set/'
Sun rise: <...strong...>07:24 am<../..strong..><..br ../..> 
Sun set: <..strong..>07:31 pm<../..strong..><..br.. /..>
```

Comment: It does the job, in this tiny example text, but it does not work in the script I'm trying to build..

Comment: Then you need to update your question and post the script.

Comment: I wish I could post the script, but the actual line contains <...STRONG...> and <...BR...> which the HTML of this post will execute instead of displaying...

Comment: Sun rise: <...strong...>07:24 am<../..strong..><..br ../..>                        Sun set:  <..strong..>07:31 pm<../..strong..><..br.. /..> Need to split that at Sun set, so line one will be Sun Rise, line 2 will be Sun set. Notice I had to add "..." for the line to display here.

Comment: Where would you like the split?

Comment: Need to split that at Sun set, so line one will be Sun Rise, line 2 will be Sun set

Comment: Maybe it should be sed -i 's/Sun set/\nSun set/', so it gets done in place. Also wouldn't echo erase everything else from this file besides what's echoed???

Comment: I was using echo as a way to demonstrate the use of the sed oneliner. You may need to modify this depending on your use. If you want to edit it in place and keep a backup, you can use  sed -i.bak 's/Sun set/\nSun set/' inputfile

Comment: Just tried sed -i 's/Sun set/\nSun set/' $HOME/path/to/file and it works fine, thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I add my personal implementation using `awk`, in such a way you can change the `separator` as you want.

```
echo "line 1 and line 2" | awk -v separator="and" 'BEGIN {FS=separator} $0 ~ separator {printf "%s\n%s%s", $1,FS,$2}'
```

I always prefer using `awk` because of the possibility of using variables easyly. If you want to split your line basing on other *separators*, you can simply change the `separator` value to another.

If you want to cut out the `separator` from the second line (I mean you you don't want to read "*and line 2*", but only "*line 2*"):

```
echo "line 1 and line 2" | awk -v separator="and " 'BEGIN {FS=separator} $0 ~ separator {printf "%s\n%s", $1,$2}'
```